# JavaScript jQuery Prevent Refresh after Triggering a click goes into a infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<li class="product_filter input required" id="product_filters_form_sizes_input"><fieldset class="choices"><legend class="label"><label>Sizes</label></legend><input id="product_filters_form_sizes_none" name="product_filters_form[sizes][]" type="hidden" value=""><ol class="choices-group"><li class="choice checked"><label for="product_filters_form_sizes_shortskinny"><input id="product_filters_form_sizes_shortskinny" name="product_filters_form[sizes][]" type="checkbox" value="Short/Skinny"><i class="icon checked-indicator"></i>SHORT/SKINNY</label></li>
  <li class="choice"><label for="product_filters_form_sizes_shortslim"><input id="product_filters_form_sizes_shortslim" name="product_filters_form[sizes][]" type="checkbox" value="Short/Slim"><i class="icon checked-indicator"></i>SHORT/SLIM</label></li>
  <li class="choice"><label for="product_filters_form_sizes_shortathletic"><input id="product_filters_form_sizes_shortathletic" name="product_filters_form[sizes][]" type="checkbox" value="Short/Athletic"><i class="icon checked-indicator"></i>SHORT/ATHLETIC</label></li>
  <li class="choice"><label for="product_filters_form_sizes_shortbroad"><input id="product_filters_form_sizes_shortbroad" name="product_filters_form[sizes][]" type="checkbox" value="Short/Broad"><i class="icon checked-indicator"></i>SHORT/BROAD</label></li>
</li>
```

By default I want the following to be selected, so I'm clicking on using JS/jQuery:

```
<li class="choice"><label for="product_filters_form_sizes_shortslim"><input id="product_filters_form_sizes_shortslim" name="product_filters_form[sizes][]" type="checkbox" value="Short/Slim"><i class="icon checked-indicator"></i>SHORT/SLIM</label></li>
```

I've tried with the following JS:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $( "#product_filters_form_sizes_shortslim" ).trigger( "click", function(){
  });
});
```

This works but it goes into an infinite loop, the behaviour looks like:

page loads -> click is triggered -> page refreshes -> click is triggered again -> page rereshes again and it goes on and on...

adding return false, return same behaviour.

```
jQuery(function($){
  $( "#product_filters_form_sizes_shortslim" ).trigger( "click", function(){
    return false;
  });
});
```

I also tried:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $( "#product_filters_form_sizes_shortslim" ).trigger( "click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Same behaviour, it loads slightly delayed than previous one, but reloads and goes into a loop.

Also tried:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $( "#product_filters_form_sizes_form_sizes_shortslim" ).click(function{
    return false;
  });
});
```

Nothings happens, unless I do:

```
$( "#product_filters_form_sizes_form_sizes_shortslim" ).click()
```

Same infinite loop.

Also when `1i` is clicked, it changes from `<li class="choice">` to `<li class="choice checked">`

And I'm using this with Rails and Spree, so no changes to HTML changes can be made.

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now, so any help or even tips on how to fix this Would greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: `trigger(eventName, extraParameters)` That function you are passing in does NOT get run.

Comment: So do you have code that submits the form when an item is checked? Because clicking a checkbox should not submit a form.

Comment: yes, on click the form gets submitted, the `li.choice` becomes `li.choice checked`

Comment: So that is why you have the infinite loop. So I am guessing that you do not want it to submit, just set the checked property. Now I wonder why you are not just setting the checked property. `$( "#product_filters_form_sizes_form_sizes_shortslim" ).prop("checked", true);`

Comment: sorry, I was unclear, when selected, `<li class="choice checked">` it gets changed to that, so I just need to change the class? would you know how to do that?

Comment: So use jQuery to add the class `$( "#product_filters_form_sizes_form_sizes_shortslim" ).addClass("sadsadsadsa");`